# getting null pointer exception java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()

Tags: java, android, proguard, google-directions-api

I implemented Direction API in my app it works perfectly on debug build but getting crash on release build I think it is because of proguard rules what rule I want to add in proguard to resolve this issue.

```
private void getDirections() {
            DirectionsResult result = getDirectionsDetails("place_id:" + pickupPlaceID, "place_id:" + dropPlaceID, TravelMode.DRIVING);
            if (result != null) {
                addPolyline(result);
                positionCamera(result.routes[0]);
            }
    }

private DirectionsResult getDirectionsDetails(String origin, String destination, TravelMode mode) {
            return DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext).mode(mode).origin(origin).destination(destination).await();
        
    }
private void addPolyline(DirectionsResult results) {

                try {

                    DirectionsRoute[] routes = results.routes;
                    DirectionsRoute route = routes[0];
                    EncodedPolyline overviewPolyline = route.overviewPolyline; //getting error here
                    String encodedPath = overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath();
                    List<LatLng> decodedPath = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPath);
                    nGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPath));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
System.err com.example.newapp at com.example.newapp.ui.home.HomeFragment.lambda$addPolyline$30(HomeFragment.java:1110)
```

Comment: The `results.routes` returns an empty array, but you don't have any guard against it

Comment: @Pavel but it works on debug build

Comment: maybe compare your configuration of the direction api connection between the debug and release build

Comment: @Pavel thank you sir it actually proguard issue only I resolved by adding this `-keep class com.google.maps.model.DirectionsRoute` `-keep class com.google.maps.model.EncodedPolyline` `-keep class com.google.maps.model.DirectionsLeg`